# apache HttpClient, upload a file via form: use StringBody instead of FileBody

Tags: java, http, httpclient

A web server expects a file to be uploaded via an html form.

This is the way how i construct the MultipartEntity, that already works:

```
FileBody filePart = new FileBody(new File("emptyFile.txt"), "text/plain");
FormBodyPart fbp = new FormBodyPart("UploadService", filePart);
MultipartEntity mpe = new MultipartEntity();  
mpe.addPart(fbp);
```

The fact is that i have my data in memory, so i don't like the idea of saving it to disk, and so I've tried to replace

```
FileBody filePart = new FileBody(new File("emptyFile.txt"), "text/plain");
```

with

```
StringBody filePart = new StringBody("");
```

But the second way doesn't work, the server returns a HTTP 500 exception; logging the data on the wire, i noticed that the only difference is as follows:

HTTP POST trace when FileBody has been used:

```
...
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UploadService"; filename="emptyFile.txt"
...
```

HTTP POST trace when StringBody has been used:

```
...
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UploadService"
...
```

That is, in the FileBody upload, it is specified a "filename" that is not specified in the StringBody upload.
How can i fix this?

Comment: What is the server framework, and what exactly says the error log on the server side? To me, this should be fixed on the server, because the filename-parm parameter is entirely optional and should only be treated as a hint, so a server can't crash if an invalid one (or no one, like in this case) is supplied

Comment: Ok, this is interesting, but here I would like to improve my control over the HttpClient API.

Answer (score 1):

With a `StringBody` you won't be able [to set a filename](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/xref/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/StringBody.html#160). But you can extend `StringBody` and override `getFilename()` to not return `null`.

According to the sources for [`FormBodyPart`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/xref/org/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart.html#87), this should be enough to have the desired filename-parm parameter:

```
 protected void generateContentDisp(final ContentBody body) {
     StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
     buffer.append("form-data; name=\"");
     buffer.append(getName());
     buffer.append("\"");
     if (body.getFilename() != null) {
         buffer.append("; filename=\"");
         buffer.append(body.getFilename());
         buffer.append("\"");
     }
     addField(MIME.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, buffer.toString());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just dropping this here, as I had the issue and kept coming here in my searches... Similar to the approach above, but I guess it is simpler.

```
public class StringFileBody extends FileBody {

    private String data;

    public StringFileBody( String input, ContentType contentType ) {

        super( new File( "." ), contentType );

        data = input;
    }

    public StringFileBody( String input, ContentType contentType, String fileName ) {

        super( new File( "." ), contentType, fileName );

        data = input;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo( OutputStream out ) throws IOException {

        out.write( data.getBytes( ) );
    }

    @Override
    public long getContentLength( ) {

        return data.getBytes( ).length;
    }
}
```